# what difference between while(*p){p++;} ,while (*++p){;} and while(*p++){;}?

Tags: c

It's about `strcat` function.

```
while (*p)
    p++;
```

and

```
while (*++p)
    ;
```

both works, but

```
while (*p++)
    ;
```

does not work. I think first and third should be same, but it's not.

Comment: 2 and 3 would only be equal if pre and post increment were the same operator

Comment: `while (*p++)` does not make `strcat` function works.

Comment: What is "works" and "does not work" supposed to mean in this case? I can write a `strcat` function using any of the three and all of them will "work" perfectly.

Comment: @AndreyT: I'm going to take a massive leap and assume that this is the first line of our proposed `strcat` implementation, and that the next line is a call to `strcpy` with `p` as the destination.

Comment: Correction, not the first line, because `strcpy` returns the original destination. So there needs to be another pointer equal to `p` before we start moving `p`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Precisely. But since we are writing `strcat`, I don't think we should use `strcpy` either, meaning that the actual copying should also be spelled out explicitly. Maybe we should outsource...

Comment: Anyway, I think the question is about why these code snippets are different, not about how to implement `strcat`. The usefulness of one or more of the snippets in implementing `strcat` is interesting but (I think) irrelevant. And I think we can probably call `strcpy` from `strcat` whether we have to implement it ourselves or not, provided that we implement `strcpy` *first* :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both

```
while (*p) p++;
```

and

```
while (*++p) ;
```

will advance `p` to point to the 0 terminator in a string, whereas

```
while (*p++) ;
```

will advance `p` to point one character past the 0 terminator.

To see why, let's assume the following characters in memory:

```
Address         0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03
-------         ---- ---- ---- ----
0x8000           'a'  'b'  'c'   0
0x8004           ...
```

Assume that `p` starts at address 0x8000.  Here's how the first loop plays out:

```
1.  *p = 'a'
2.  p = 0x8001
3.  *p = 'b'
4.  p = 0x8002
5.  *p = 'c'
6.  p = 0x8003
7.  *p = 0
8.  end loop
```

Here's how the second loop plays out:

```
1.  p = 0x8001
2.  *p = 'b'
3.  p = 0x8002
4.  *p = 'c'
5.  p = 0x8003
6.  *p = 0
7.  end loop
```

And here's the last one:

```
1.  *p = 'a'
2.  p = 0x8001
3.  *p = 'b'
4.  p = 0x8002
5.  *p = 'c'
6.  p = 0x8003
7.  *p = 0;
8.  p = 0x8004
9.  end loop
```

In the last version, evaluating `*p++` advances the pointer even if the value of `*p` is 0.

Comment: The expanded explanation w/ expected output is nice.

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume that `p` is a string.

```
while (*p) p++; /* (1) */
while (*++p) ;  /* (2) */
while (*p++) ;  /* (3) */
```

- **(1)** is different from **(2)** if `p` is an empty string.
- **(1)** is different from **(3)** because with **(3)**, even if the current value of `*p` is a `'\0'` character, `p` is incremented.

Answer (score 2):

```
// move p forward as long as it points to a non-0 character,
// leave it pointing to a 0 character.
while (*p) p++;  

// move p forward until it points to a 0 character, skipping the first 
// character before you start
while (*++p);

// move p forward until it points one past a 0 character
while (*p++);
```

So given that (1) "works": (2) also works if `p` initially points to a non-empty string. (3) doesn't work at all because `p` ends up pointing to a different place.

`*++p` increments `p` and then evaluates to whatever `p` now points to. `*p++` evaluates to whatever `p` initially points to, but also increments `p`. Hence (2) and (3) are different.

(1) and (3) are different because (3) executes the `p++`, then it decides whether to stop. (1) first looks at `*p` to decide whether to stop, and if not stopping it executes the `p++`.

Answer (score 0):

*++p means increment this variable, then use it
*p++ means use the variable, then increment it